# Twig table get id outside for loop

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to access to the user id outside my for loop in twig

*Table*

```
        {% set userid = '' %}
        <table class="display dataTable" id="manageusertable"  cellspacing="0" width="100%">

         <thead>
           <tr>
             <th>Image</th>
             <th>Login</th>
             <th>Nom / Prenom</th>
             <th>Email</th>
             <th>Activé</th>
             <th>Actions</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
            <tfoot>
            </tfoot>
               <tbody>

                 {% for user in users %}

                 {% set userid = user.id %}
                 <tr class="getid">  

                   <td>{{ user.UserImage }}</td>
                   <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
                   <td>{{ user.UserLastname  }} / {{ user.UserFirstName  }}
                   </td>
                   <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                   {% if user.enabled == 1 %}
                   <td><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                   {% else %}
                   <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                   {% endif %}
                   <td>
                   <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-add btn-sm" data-
                   toggle="modal" data-target="#update"><i class="fa fa-
                  pencil"></i></button>
                   <button type="button" class="deleteuser btn btn-danger 
                  btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteuser"><i 
                  class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> </button>                    
                   </td>
                 </tr>

                       {% endfor %}
               </tbody>

              </table>
```

*Modal div when button data-model=#delete is clicked (outside loop)*

```
         <div class="modal fade" id="deleteuser" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                 <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header modal-header-primary">
                       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                       <h3><i class="fa fa-user m-r-5"></i> Delete User</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                       <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                             <form class="form-horizontal">
                                <fieldset>

                                   <div class="col-md-12 form-group user-form-group">
                                      <label class="control-label">Delete User</label>
                                      <div class="pull-right">
                                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">NO</button>
                                        <button " class="btn btn-add btn-sm"><a style="color:#fff;" href="{{ path('lemon_user_deleteuser', {'id': userid}) }}">YES</a></button>
                                      </div>
                                   </div>
                                </fieldset>
                             </form>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <!-- /.modal-content -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
           </div>
```

The line
`<button " class="btn btn-add btn-sm"><a style="color:#fff;" href="{{ path('lemon_user_deleteuser', {'id': userid}) }}">YES</a></button>`

always returns the last id (15 if i have 15users in my DB) no matter on which line the button is clicked

i know how to do this with jquery/ajax and from scratch php but since im new to symfony/twig im kinda lost

Comment: Can't be done. Either you generate a button for each user inside the `for` loop or you involve some JavaScript.

Comment: can i pass a jquery .val() to twig ?

Comment: Not without ajax you don't. Twig is parsed server side

Comment: `<button type="button" class="deleteuser btn btn-danger 
                  btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteuser" data-userid="{{ userid }}">` is a start. You then need to read that out and change the url when the modal opens.

Comment: got it working, thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have to make an array with the whole of ids e.g.

```
             {{ set userIds = {} }}
             {% for user in users %}
             ...
               {% set userIds = userIds|merge({id : user.id} %}
             ...
             {% endfor %}
```

And then redo the "for loop" for each delete button and paths setup